# How to add condition to calculate the temporal correlation for huge data?

Tags: r, correlation

I want to calculate the correlation between two datasets with a condition from another data.I want the top 50% of P, this corresponds to the values of P greater than the median.

```
      P=c(1,6,5,6,2,8,5)
      sf=c(1,2,6,6,4,5,5)
      Pf=c(1,6,5,8,4,8,5)
```

normal corr:

```
     cor(sf,Pf)
```

with condition:

```
      cor(sf[P > median(P)], Pf[P > median(P)])
```

this worked perfectly.How Can I apply the same thing with my real data?

```
  with condition(using dir3(p is dir3 here)):

              ???
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same code should work:

```
function(x){cor(x[,1],x[,2])}
```

can be written as

```
function(x) { 
  P  <- x[,3]
  sf <- x[,1]
  Pf <- x[,2]
  cor(sf, Pf)
}
```

which becomes

```
function(x) { 
  P  <- x[,3]
  sf <- x[,1]
  Pf <- x[,2]
  i <- P > median(P)
  cor(sf[i], Pf[i])
}
```

Comment: This could be due to missing values in `P`:
you can try `i <- which( P > median(P, na.rm=TRUE) )`.
This could also be due to missing values in `x[,1]` and `x[,2]`:
you can try `cor(sf[i], Pf[i], use="complete.obs")`.

Comment: If you have a lot of ties in your data, the condition `P > median(P)` could be empty.